# Mobile emulation for responsive application testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mobile, emulation

I'm working on an web application that is responsive. I'm able to use the chrome mobile emulation option to launch the browser into the configuration I need. But since the Responsive is not set on Chrome options, I'm not getting the desired results.

Here is my code. According to the mobile Emulation option I can either use predefined device configurations or use device metrics to configure the resolution. But I would need to use the responsive option in chrome. How I can do this?

I mean to use the Responsive in the Device drop down

[image]

```
Map<String, Object> deviceMetrics = new HashMap<>();
deviceMetrics.put("width", 320);
deviceMetrics.put("height", 533);
 
Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()

options.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation",mobileEmulation);
```

Comment: I figured the solution to this. I missed the user agent part. after adding the user agent , it works.

Comment: mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko)